# Add icon to ApplicationCommands.Cut, ApplicationCommands.Copy,... in WPF

Tags: wpf, command, contextmenu

I'm using ApplicationCommand.Copy, ApplicationCommands.Cut, and others to add clipboard support to my application. This sets the text and shortcut text of my menuitems. Is there a way to define the icon for these commands so I get the same icon wherever these commands get used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality relies on the properties of [`RoutedUICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routeduicommand.aspx), there is none for the icon. You could subclass `MenuItem` for example and add some `Dictionary<RoutedUICommand,ImageSource>`, which you then can use internally.